# How to create a data validation drop down list in excel that is conditional based on if it is blank

Tags: database, excel, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a table with vendors on the y axis and items they sell on the x axis. I'm trying to figure out a way to make a data validation list that will show the vendor names that sell the certain item.

For example:  Store A, B, and C are columns across the top, and Apple, Orange, and Banana are items that are rows along the left. Store A and B sell apples and have prices for how much the apples cost, but not store C. I want a drop down list next to apples in a seperate sheet that has Store A and B in it. If only Store B and C sell oranges, then I want a drop down list next to Oranges that has only those stores in it. This seperate sheet will then the hlookup function to auto populate the unit price for use in budgeting.

To recap, I am making a budget excel spreadsheet sheet that references a table of unit prices for a series of vendors and uses it in a table of items next to a drop down list of vendors that auto populates the unit prices using the hlookup function. I don't know how to make a list formula in data validation that only takes vendor names that have a unit price for that specific item.

I have a feeling it uses something with the index and matching functions, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Link to Picture of Final Spreadsheet where drop down menus are***
[image]

***Link to the table that has the prices of the vendors and specific items that the drop down list will be referencing***
[image]

Comment: Can you put screenshot or data for better understanding?

Comment: Sure thing, just added two.

Comment: From your first image I assume that, material are given then you want to populate drop-downs in `vendor` column whose have prices in second image, right? Can you please share a sample workbook so that we can directly work on that. Upload in google drive then share download link here.

Comment: This would be much easier if you allow to use a helper column (Extra column to put some formula). Then you can hide that column.